# Security sandbox violation when connecting to Socket from flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, sockets

I am using a Socket (not xmlSocket) connection between flex applications and the server pushing messages.

Now, when I connect from the local machine to the server everything is working file and running, connection is succesful and I get data back and forth.

When I upload the application (flex) to the server and run it from there, I get a security sandBox violation message.

Note:
1. I do have a crossdomain file with * wildcard both on port and on domain.
2. I created a Securiy.allowDomain("*") as well.

Another thing.
I also created another listener on that same server, listening to connections for port 843 (default) and this service just waited for a connection send policy file to the client and that's it.

That did not solve the problem as well...

That's next?
What should I do to fix the problem?

Appreciate your help.

Avi

Comment: Does your listener who serves policy files run on some Linux distribution, then you probably have to run it as "administrator" because the port is < 1024?

Comment: Runs on a windows 2008 machine, the server is also running IIS7 with several application on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for this issue was a dedicated policy file serving server.
I implemented a socket listening to the dedicated port where flex is looking for policy file, once I got a connection and a request I answered right back with the appropriate policy file.

This solved the problem for all users and is working very well for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

did you try [`Security.loadPolicyFile`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Security.html#loadPolicyFile%28%29)? Does your server on port ever actually 843 receive policy file requests (that's a tiny XML sent to request the crossdomain policy file)? Does your actual server ever receive policy file requests? What traffic do you get on your server?

greetz
back2dos

Comment: I do get the request and respond with the appropriate response.
I do loadPolicyFile from my IIS and it loads the file OK but does not help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    .NET
    Add crossdomain.xml to your Web server root directory, for example, 
C:\inetpub\wwwroot.

    Java
    Add crossdomain.xml to \ArcGIS\java\web_output, for example, 
C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\java\web_output.
```

http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/flex/help/content/deploy_application.htm